# No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'initWithBase64Encoding:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am trying to build in xcode but I keep getting this issue

```
No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'initWithBase64Encoding:'
```

and

```
No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'base64Encoding'
```

I have looked everywhere not but there isn't a clear solution to my problem. These are what's giving me problem:

```
- (NSString*)stringFromImage:(UIImage*)image 
  {
      if(image) 
      {
          UIImage* convertImage = [GameUtility imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(80, 80)];
          NSData *dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(convertImage, 30);
          return [dataObj base64Encoding];
      }
      return @"";
  }

- (UIImage*)imageFromString:(NSString*)imageString 
  {
       NSData* imageData =[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:imageString];
       return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
  }
```

Comment: @Zaph: Compiling with ARC won't allow you to invoke an unknown selector (it's a hard error, as opposed to a warning).

Comment: @dreamlax True but the error is not really an ARC issue.

Answer (score 1):

[use this base64 file for encode and decode](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)

```
- (NSString*)stringFromImage:(UIImage*)image 
   { 
      if(image) 
      { 
          UIImage* convertImage = [GameUtility imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(80, 80)]; 
          NSData *dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(convertImage, 30); 
          return [dataObj base64EncodedString]; 
       } 
      return @""; 
   } 

 - (UIImage *)imageFromString:(NSString*)imageString 
   { 
      NSData* imageData =[imageString base64DecodedData]; 
      return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; 
   }
```

Comment: Hi Jignesh. Thank you. I just did and imported it with "#import "Base64.h"" - I am still getting the error.

Comment: More errors. "Interface type 'UIImage' cannot be returned by value; did you forget * in 'UIImage'?" - "Interface type cannot be statically allocated" and "No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'base64EncodedString'"

Comment: It is still there. "Interface type cannot be statically allocated"

Comment: "No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'base64EncodedString'"

Comment: try  #import "NSString+Base64"
#import "NSData+Base64"

Comment: "No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'base64DecodedData'"

Comment: I think problem is import file in Base64.h file have two category for NSString and NSData

Comment: After importing, I got "Interface type cannot be statically allocated"

Comment: Down to one final error "No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'base64DecodedData'"

Comment: @user2740929 ya its my typo mistake check edited ans

Comment: @user2740929 What is the OS (OSX or iOS) and version you are compiling for?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited but but I am still left with "No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'base64DecodedData'"

Comment: I am compiling for iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your image to string like this first. And then you can try convert your `UIImage` to `NSData` & then convert that data into string by using `encodeBase64WithData`

```
NSString * Image = [self encodeBase64WithData:[imageDict objectForKey:@"Image"]];
```

and then try your `UIImage` to string like this

```
[UIImage imageWithData: [self decodeBase64WithString:[registerDataDict objectForKey:@"Image"]]];
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: "Use of undeclared identifier 'imageDict'" - "Use of undeclared identifier 'registerDataDict'" and "No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'base64Encoding'"

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting OS X 10.9 or iOS 7 you can use the [`base64EncodedStringWithOptions:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW38) method to encode the string, and the [`initWithBase64EncodedString:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW14) method to decode the string.

If you are targeting platforms earlier than this, you need to either write these methods yourself or find a library that implements them for you (as category methods of `NSData`). Different libraries will have different names for these methods, so make sure you check with that library's documentation or check the header.